# Android, HTML, Debug, webview stack trace

Tags: android, html, webview, local-storage

I have an Android application with WebView and index.html in assets.
There is such thing in HTML like localStorage.
In my index.html I have script: `localStorage.setItem("key", "value");`

Is there any way to debug webkit, or to see stack trace when we call localStorage.setItem ?
I want to see which methods called in native from the beginning to the end.

I think there should be some possibility.
I believe have not enough debug skills.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    browser.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);

    browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

Index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to tell if webview gives an error with that code.

Comment: Is that in javascript all?

Comment: simple index.html, where I call javascript localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

Comment: How do you call it? Who is calling it? When? Where?

Comment: That is code how to lode a html file from assets. Nice to know but not an answer to my question. Please reread.

Comment: In HTML? You mean HTML5 Web Storage Objects? and `window.localStorage`?

Comment: If you had told this all at start (please adapt the title/subject of this thread) and had explained about local storage i would not have reacted on your post as no experience. You need something like a javascript console? Arent there better tools available if you develop that page on pc?

Comment: PC ? I'm working on android device, and I need to know how webview interacts with android jni. I know that Android has android.webkit package that works with WebView. This webkit includes jni libraries like libwebcore.so. And when I called localstorage.setItem, webview definitely calls some webcore methods. I need to know which one

Comment: The whole source of webview will somewhere be on the internet.